# Speeding up SOLR search

Tags: solr

The SOLR search response is extremely slow using SOLR Apache Lucene 3.6.

Some performance enhancement techniques I'm experimenting with are

- SOLR Pagination
- mergeFactor currently set to 10 in solrConfig.xml
- SOLR Facet queries
- filterCache in solrconfig.xml set to size 512 and using
  solr.FastLRUCache and  autowarm = 0;
- queryResultCache in solfconfig.xml set to size 512 with
  autowarmCount=0
- newSearcher, firstSearcher, and useColdSearcher
- single segment index for 100,000 documents
- single machine SOLR server for 100,000 documents

How can I optimize items 1-7 to increase SOLR search response for a term/query?
Are there any other optimization parameters to consider not mentioned above?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can also check below :-

1. [SolrPerformanceFactors](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceFactors)
2. [ImproveSearchingSpeed](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/ImproveSearchingSpeed)
3. [ImproveIndexingSpeed](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/ImproveIndexingSpeed)
4. [SolrCaching](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching)
5. [The Seven Deadly Sins of Solr](https://lucidworks.com/post/the-seven-deadly-sins-of-solr/)

Comment: Please provide comments when voting down an answer. Sure helps.